# How to use spacebar and if statements in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am making a game based off of a tutorial at http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/ it is going well but I wanted to make the function that reads if the two items are touching only happen when the space bar is pressed.

```
if (hero.x <= (monster.x + 32)
    && monster.x <= (hero.x + 32)
    && hero.y <= (monster.y + 32)
    && monster.y <= (hero.y + 32)) {
  ++monstersCaught;
  reset();
}

if (hero.x <= (tack.x + 32)
    && tack.x <= (hero.x + 32)
    && hero.y <= (tack.y + 32)
    && tack.y <= (hero.y + 32)) {
  monstersCaught -= monstersCaught;
  reset();
}

if (monstersCaught > 10) {
  monstersCaught -= 10;
}
```

How should I fix the

```
if (hero.x <= (tack.x + 32)
    && tack.x <= (hero.x + 32)
    && hero.y <= (tack.y + 32)
    && tack.y <= (hero.y + 32)) {
  monstersCaught -= monstersCaught;
  reset();
}
```

so that it only goes if the space bar is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most easy way is to know at any moment the status of your keyboard : for that you have to listen to keyboard events and update an array containing the status of each key.

This will lead to something like :

```
window.keyStates = [];   // now you can use keyStates anywhere. 
                       // good enough since you seem to be in the first steps.

window.addEventListener('keydown',
          function(e) { keyStates[e.keyCode || e.key] = true;} );

window.addEventListener('keyup', 
          function(e) { keyStates[e.keyCode || e.key] = false;} );
```

Once you have done that, you can test anywhere, anytime, the status of the space key with :

```
if (keyStates[32] == true) { ... }
```

you might prefer, for readability, define a key object that will hold the few keycodes you use :

```
window.key = {
     space : 32,
     enter : 13,
     left  : 37,
     up    : 38,
     right : 39,
    down : 40
}
```

that way, you can write :

```
if ( keyStates[key.space] == true ) {  
     ... 
}
```

which is more easy to grasp.

(Rq : if you search for keycodes, looking here is one way : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent )

Comment: Do you know anyway to have two statements after the if before the resolution?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand. is : 'If ( keyStates[key.space] == true && keyState[key.down] == true )' an example ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery you can do something similar to this:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32) {
        //do your logic here
    }
});
```

32 is the keycode for spacebar

Or in just javascript (Run this code in Document ready as displayunicode(event)):

```
function displayunicode(e){
   var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
   if(unicode == 32){
       //do your code
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to in JS?

Comment: @GREM it checks if the the spacebar has been pressed (keycode 32).  If the handler returns 32 then you can perform you logic.